# Bittorrent, tracker announce url is a local IP

Tags: bittorrent

A friend has set up a tracker for testing purposes. When he creates a torrent, I can open it in ordinary bittorrent clients and download/upload as usual. The tracker url in the meta info is in the form http://192.168.1.X/somefolder/announce.php

How can this work? Isn't that a local ip from within a LAN? Still my bittorrent client can find the tracker and communicate with it over the internet.

Comment: probably the good address is not this one ;) it's definetly a local ip :)

Comment: Are you on the same network as your friend?

Comment: Are you sure it can find the tracker and isn't using DHT?

Comment: Yes, I see it's using DHT. I'm not completely sure how this impacts matters but I'll read up on it more before further questions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be using DHT which means that the peer lists are exchanged decentrally.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using DHT the meta info may simply contain an `announce-list` entry.

If an `announce-list` is present most Bittorrent clients will use trackers from that list and ignore the `announce` entry.